# Azure create servicePrincipal results in Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to create a new service principal using the command below using azure cli v2.0.

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name ServicePrincipalName
Changing "ServicePrincipalName" to a valid URI of "http://ServicePrincipalName", which is the required format used for service principal names
Found an existing application instance of "abcd-8f27-47cf-9976-xkkfigif5e1de". We will patch it
Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

I am not sure what privileges the Azure Admin of my tenant should assign to my user so i can create a servicePrincipal any guidelines or document pointers please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to know what this command will do. The command `az ad sp create-for-rbac --name ServicePrincipalName` will create an AD App(app registration) along with a service principal in your tenant, the AD App will have an `Application ID URI` named `http://ServicePrincipalName`, a `Display name` named `ServicePrincipalName`. Then the command will add the service principal to your subscription as a `Contributor`.

The error you got means there is already an AD App with the `Application ID URI` equals `http://ServicePrincipalName` existing in your tenant. And you are not the `Owner` of the AD App. (Note: in the tenant, the `Display name` is not unique, but the `Application ID URI` is.)

To solve the issue and use this command successfully, follow the tips below.

1.Change the `ServicePrincipalName` to a different one. (Or if your admin allow you to use the existing AD App mentioned above, just let him add your user account as an `Owner` to the AD App. - not recommend)

2.If your account's `User type` is just a `Member` in the tenant. Make sure in the portal -> AAD -> `User settings` -> `Users can register applications` is `Yes`. If your account is a `Guest` , except the `Users can register applications` need to be `Yes`, also `User settings` -> `External collaboration settings` -> `Guest users permissions are limited` need to be `No`.

3.Your user account should be the `Owner` of the subscription. Otherwise you can create the service principal successfully, but you cannot add it to the subscription.

Comment: I have the same issues while creating service principle, after upgrade the azure cli version to latest, I am able to create service principle successfully  az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "myterraform1" --role="Contributor"